# Failed opening '.../includes/src/__adminhtml.php' for inclusion

Tags: php, magento

I can't access Magento admin side I'm getting white screen and when I turn on error reporting I'm getting this message:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => include_once(): Failed opening '/home/domain/www/www/includes/src/__adminhtml.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/domain/www/www/includes/src:.:/usr/local/php56/lib/php')
    [file] => /home/domanin/www/www/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php
    [line] => 108
)
```

So basically I don't have __adminhtml.php file inside my includes folder after clearing the compiled files and run compilation again, clearing the cache, everything is still the same.

One strange thing is that I'm always getting Compiler: Disabled status when I run:

```
php -f shell/compiler.php -- state
```

Even after running:

```
1. php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
2. php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear
3. php -f shell/compiler.php -- compile
4. php -f shell/compiler.php -- enable
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: You need to run `compiler.php` from within the `shell` folder for it to accurately report the status.

Comment: @Joe Yes, you are right, when I run `-- state` command from within the `shell` folder it reports:

`Compiler Status: Enabled
Compilation State: Compiled
Collected Files Count: 7159
Compiled Scopes Count: 4`

So that is not a problem then... :/

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?

Comment: @Joe 1.9.3.6 now, and all chaos started after I upgraded from v 1.7.0.x

Answer (score 0):

In my 1.9.3.6 instance, `__adminhtml.php` is not generated.

However, in Varien_Autoload.php, you site is breaking here:

```
static public function registerScope($code)
    {
        self::$_scope = $code;
        if (defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
            @include_once COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::SCOPE_FILE_PREFIX.$code.'.php';
        }
    }
```

Specifically, line 108:

```
@include_once COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::SCOPE_FILE_PREFIX.$code.'.php';
```

The `@` symbol means that it shouldn't error out if it doesn't find the file.

I would check this line in `lib/Varien/Autoload.php` and add the `@` symbol if it's not there. Also, check if it's been copied to `app/code/local/Varien/Autoload.php` and fix it there as well. Then clear out and re-run your compilation process.

If that's not the issue, then it could be related to the error reporting. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php. Something could have overridden the default behavior to throw an error when the file is not found.

You might have an extension or tool that is setting a custom error handler. Grep for `set_error_handler` and `setErrorHandler` and see if any files come up in `app/code/local` or `app/code/community`. You will need to fix the error handler to return false if error_reporting is zero. Example:

```
// From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php
if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
    // This error code is not included in error_reporting, so let it fall
    // through to the standard PHP error handler
    return false;
}
```

If it's not an extension, the last place to look is `functions.php`. The default error handler `mageCoreErrorHandler()` is what is used by default. It's probably been modified. Check if you have a copy in `app/code/local/Mage/Core/functions.php`. If you do, then either replace the `mageCoreErrorHandler()` method with the code from the 1.9.3.6 source, or fix it like in the above example.

If you don't have a copy in local, then it's possible your core `functions.php` file is corrupt and you need to replace it with a fresh copy from the 1.9.3.6 source (or if it's customized, copy it to `app/code/local`, fix the error reporting, and keep an unaltered 1.9.3.6 version in `app/code/core`).

Comment: Those lines inside `lib/Varien/Autoload.php` are the same as yours. Nothing is strange there, but inside `app/code/local` I don't have Varien there. 

Also that error reporting was turned on by me, by placing the `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);` in my index.php.